# Backward compatibility in Safari iOS 11 (grid-gap). I am using tailwind and the postcss plugin "postcss-preset-env"

Tags: css, gridview, safari, tailwind-css, postcss

I am using Tailwind in my project. I would like to keep backward compatibility with safari iOS 11.
My problem occurs when I use grid. The postcss plugin does not change the css `gap` property to `grid-gap`.

I am trying to use the `postcss-preset-env` plugin for postcss. I run postcss through postcss cli.

This is my configuration of the postcss.config.js file:

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import'),
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
        postcssPresetEnv({
            browsers: 'defaults, iOS >= 11',
            preserve: false,
            features: {
                "gap-properties": true
            }
        }),
        cssnano({preset: 'default'})
    ]
}
```

My devDependencies:

```
"cssnano": "^6.0.1",
"postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
"postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
"postcss-preset-env": "^8.4.1",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

`postcss-preset-env` does not change `gap` into `grid-gap`.

These are two different properties and changing one into the other would be a bug, not a feature :)

If you want to use Tailwind and require compatibility with older browser versions you need to file an issue or open a discussion with Tailwind on GitHub : https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss